# Hides nodes of Tree Object Recursive

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, recursion, tree

I'm looking for a way to hides node in a tree.
I'm filtering a node with a node type, this is my original structure:

```
root
 +FolderA
    -File1
    -File2
    -File3
 +FolderB
    -File4
    -File5
    +FolderB-1
            -File6
```

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
+root
 -File1
 -File2
 -File3
 -File4
 -File5
 -File6
```

I have created my class XNode with a type and a list of childrens.
(this is pseudo language for abbreviation)

```
Class XNode
  MyType type;
  string Name;
  List<XNode> childrens; 
End Class
```

I have created a factory class that query my database and create original tree.

I have created a Xaml treeView UserControl to bind my root XNode created.

Via Xaml is not possible to hide a Node, this operation must be done with binded object (my root Xnode created).

**Now my question is: 
There are recursive alghoritms to cancel a "Folder type" node, get its childrens and add them to parent Node?**

I'm try:

```
  public XNode RemoveFoldersElements(ref XNode rootNode)
    {

        if (rootNode != null)
        {
            if (rootNode.Children.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < rootNode.Children.Count; i++)
                {
                    XNode children = rootNode.Children.ElementAt(i);
                    if (children.WType == NodeType.Type_FOLDER)
                    {
                        XNode tempNode = RemoveFoldersElements(ref children);
                        if (tempNode != null)
                            rootNode.Children.Add(tempNode);
                        rootNode.Children.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RemoveFoldersElements(ref children);
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

but not success because not all nodes of Type_FOLDER are erased (it jump one level) !
Any Idea?

Comment: Can you just recurse each node, build a list of all the files, then add them as children to the root at the end? It seems like you're trying to do too much work if you only care about the order, and not the hierarchy.

Comment: This is a lazy mode. I want to filter this tree that have various type of items (not only files)

Comment: Your example used Files and Folders so I responded in that context. I don't understand what is "lazy mode" about it, apply your filter to the children as you recurse and only build the list with your desired types.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's the idea, flatten the tree while filtering:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> Flatten<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TSource>> childCollectionSelector, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
{
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if(predicate(item))
            yield return item;
        foreach (var subitem in childCollectionSelector(item).Flatten(childCollectionSelector, predicate).Where(predicate))
        {
            yield return subitem;
        }
    }
}
```

and you could use it like this:

```
var rootList = new []{rootElement}; // Flattening works on the collection
var files = rootList.Flatten(x => x.children, x => x.type == MyType.FILE);
```

And it will work, granted you don't have any circular references and all collections are initialized. If you do have circular dependencies, you will say hello to `StackOverflowException`...

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works, but i've to hide different Types of nodes. The root Node is an object that not implements IEnumerable interface...

Comment: @user1696549 Then wrap it in the collection like I did in the example, it's probably the easiest way. I'm not sure what you mean by 'hiding different types of nodes', that's something left out to filtering - you'd have to specify your filter function.